# How start a local VM built by packer?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, packer

I am new to packer.
For a start I tried to build: https://github.com/shiguredo/packer-templates/tree/develop/ubuntu-14.04 which worked fine. But when I want to sin it up via `vagrant up` I get the following error:

```
Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again.
```

After calling `vagrant init` a config file which looks like a default config file is created. But still there are errors:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'parallels' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: parallels
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: parallels
    default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Downloads/packer-templates-develop/ubuntu-14.04/base
```

How can I start my packer-generated VM locally?
Is the only solution to keep track of the Vagrantfile manually?

## Edit:

if I call `vagrant init myNewlyCreatedBox.box`
Then vagrant will try too boot the VM but

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "prl_fs" file system is not available. Please verify that
Parallels Tools are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. If so, the VM reboot can solve a problem.
The command attempted was:

mount -t prl_fs -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3` vagrant /vagrant
mount -t prl_fs -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those templates will generate a Vagrant box for you.  If the process completes successfully you should have `ubuntu-14-04-x64-virtualbox.box` and `ubuntu-14-04-x64-vmware.box` file as specified by `template.json` file. To use those newly created boxes in Vagrant you'll need to add the one corresponding to your specific hypervisor to the list of boxes that Vagrant knows about by the following:

`vagrant box add <nameToReferToBox> <pathToBoxYouJustCreated>`

for example

`vagrant box add ubuntu-14-04-x64 ubuntu-14-04-x64-virtualbox.box`

Then to create an instance of that box (a VM) you can simply create a Vagrant file targeting the new box you just imported:

`vagrant init ubuntu-14-04-x64`

and then spin up a VM based on the base box:

`vagrant up`